# helm3 / function "lookup" not defined

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, microk8s

I recently installed `microk8s`, and enabled helm3 and dns addons on microk8s.
Deployment from `stable/chart` works fine but any deployment from `bitnami/chart` fails.

**OS:** Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS -- microk8s:  1.19/stable

```
microk8s.helm3 install my-release bitnami/jenkins
=> Error: parse error at (jenkins/charts/common/templates/_secrets.tpl:84): function "lookup" not defined

microk8s.helm3 install my-release bitnami/magento
=> Error: parse error at (magento/charts/elasticsearch/charts/common/templates/_secrets.tpl:84): function "lookup" not defined
```

Comment: What is your Helm version?

Comment: Hi, i'm using the helm as an addon of microk8s.
`sudo microk8s helm3 version
=>version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.0.2", GitCommit:"19e47ee3283ae98139d98460de796c1be1e3975f", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.5"}

so my helm version is 3.0.2`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There was a bug reported [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts/issues/193) and [here](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/7955) which was caused by the conditional inclusion of `lookup` into the function map.

A fix for it was merged [here](https://github.com/helm/helm/pull/7969) and is now available from Helm version 3.2.0.

So, in order to fix this issue you should update your Helm to version 3.2.0 or newer.

Answer (score 2):

Faced with the same issue while installing Kafka. The solution is to install a newer version of Helm 3 and use its commands with *--kubeconfig* specified:

```
microk8s config > kubeconfig.yaml
sudo snap install helm --classic
/snap/bin/helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
/snap/bin/helm install --wait kafka bitnami/kafka --set metrics.jmx.enabled=true --kubeconfig kubeconfig.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install helm3 with snap and then link it to microk8s:

```
sudo snap install helm --classic
sudo mkdir /var/snap/microk8s/current/bin
sudo ln -s /snap/bin/helm /var/snap/microk8s/current/bin/helm
```

There seems to be some issues using helm3.0 instead of helm 3.1

Comment: Hi, thx for your help.
i got this error with your approach: Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "http://localhost:8080/version?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused

Comment: see my solution here: https://worklifenotes.com/2020/01/22/how-to-make-microk8s-work-with-helm/

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all of the information

I fixed this by using the snap helm (version 3.6.3) on ubuntu

```
microk8s config > ~/.kube/config
chmod go-r ~/.kube/config
sudo snap install helm --classic
```

then doing the helm repo add, update, and install charts without errors